# Generating items in ListVIew

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, listview, loaded

I need to generate a `listview` with data I have in an `array`

my  XAML is:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="IconTextDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60">
                <Border Background="#66727272" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10">
                    <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Loaded="Name_Loaded"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Description" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Loaded="Description_Loaded"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="IconTextGrid" Height="400" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconTextDataTemplate}" Grid.Row="4" Margin="40,40,40,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ListView>
```

And the C# code:

```
private async void SearchBox_QuerySubmitted(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            IconTextGrid.Items.Add("");
            nameStr = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
            descriptionStr = item.Email;
        }
    }


    public T FindElementByName<T>(DependencyObject element, string sChildName) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        T childElement = null;
        var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < nChildCount; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;

            if (child == null)
                continue;

            if (child is T && child.Name.Equals(sChildName))
            {
                childElement = (T)child;
                break;
            }

            childElement = FindElementByName<T>(child, sChildName);

            if (childElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return childElement;
    }

    private void Name_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock Name = FindElementByName<TextBlock>(this, "Name");
        Name.Text = nameStr;
    }

    private void Description_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock Description = FindElementByName<TextBlock>(this, "Description");
        Description.Text = descriptionStr;
    }
```

This code should generate a list view with some items (in the array size) and put in every item the data from the cell in the array.
The problem is that only in one item I see the data from the array and in the other items there is nothing.
Wish for help, thanks

Comment: @NextInLine IconTextGrid is a listview where the results from a search are displayed in, I see the correct number of items, but only one item caontains data, the others are empty, and my question is why?

Comment: @NextInLine FindElementByName Finds the textBlocks inside the DataTemplate (They are not accessible without this function)

Comment: Ah, I missed the vertical scrollbar on your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is failing for at least one reason:

```
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        IconTextGrid.Items.Add("");
        nameStr = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
        descriptionStr = item.Email;
    }
```

you appear to be storing `nameStr` and `descriptionStr` into fields. But you are only storing the last item in results.

The good news is you can simplify and fix your code all at once. Using

```
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        var nameStr = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
        var descriptionStr = item.Email;
        IconTextGrid.Items.Add(new { Name = nameStr, Description = descriptionStr });
    }
```

That will create anonymous types with `Name` and `Description` properties for the `ListView` elements. You can then use:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IconTextDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel ...>
                <Image .../>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel ...>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description} Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And remove your `FindElementByName`, `Name_Loaded`, and `Description_Loaded` methods.